# Weird Matlab Input argument error?

Tags: matlab

Hey there
I have the following Matlab code. It complains about:

??? Input argument "r" is undefined.

Error in ==> BlackScholesPriceTmp at 8
    b=r;

Code:

```
%function [price,delta,gamma,vega,theta]=BlackScholesPriceTmp(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,v,noutparams)
function [price,delta,gamma,vega,theta]=BlackScholesPriceTmp(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,v,noutparams)
delta=0;
gamma=0;
vega=0;
theta=0;

    b=r;
    d1 = (log(S / X) + (b + v ^ 2 / 2) * T) / (v * T^0.5);
    d2 = d1 - v * T^0.5;

        price=0;
    if CallPutFlag == 'c' ,
        price = S * normal_cdf(d1) - X * exp(-r * T) * normal_cdf(d2);
        %endif
    end
    if noutparams>1,
        delta=exp((b-r)*T)*normal_cdf(d1);
        theta_tmp1= -( S*exp((b-r)*T)*normal_pdf(d1)*v )/(2*T^0.5);
        theta_tmp2= -(b-r)*S*exp((b-r)*T)*normal_cdf(d1);
        theta_tmp3= -r*X*exp(-r*T)*normal_cdf(d2);
        theta=theta_tmp1+theta_tmp2+theta_tmp3;
    %end
    %endif
    else
        %price = X * exp(-r * T) * normal_cdf(-d2) - S * normal_cdf(-d1);
        price = X * exp(-r * T) * normalcdf(-d2) - S * normcdf(-d1);
    end
    if noutparams>1,
        delta=exp((b-r)*T)*(normal_cdf(d1)-1);
        theta_tmp1= -( S*exp((b-r)*T)*normal_pdf(d1)*v )/(2*T^0.5);
        theta_tmp2= (b-r)*S*exp((b-r)*T)*normal_cdf(-d1);
        theta_tmp3= r*X*exp(-r*T)*normal_cdf(-d2);
        theta=theta_tmp1+theta_tmp2+theta_tmp3;
    endif
    end
    if noutparams>1,
    gamma=(normal_pdf(d1)*exp((b-r)*T)) / (S*v*T^0.5);
    vega=S * exp((b-r)*T)*normal_pdf(d1)*T^0.5;
    endif
end
```

As being to new to Matlab, why does it complain about the r parameter but not the rest. I don't understand why the others are being complained? What am I doing right in the rest but not in r?

Comment: could you post the code you are using to call the function please.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, you are allowed to call a function with less than the number of declared input arguments. It only becomes an error if the called function tries to access the value stored in a parameter that was not specified. In that case, the error message will be the one you are getting, namely, 'Input argument "*parameterName*" is undefined.'.

MATLAB functions can use the `nargin` function to determine at run time the number of actual arguments passed. Often, the following idiom is used to provide default values for those parameters that aren't specified:

```
function foo(a, b)
if nargin < 1
    a = 0; % default for a is 0
end
if nargin < 2
    b = 1; % default for b is 1
end
... code that uses a and/or b ...
```

The function `foo` can be called in any of the following ways:

```
foo(); % equivalent to foo(0, 1);
foo(5); % equivalent to foo(5, 1);
foo(5, 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several problems apart from r

using lines containing normal_pdf() , normal_cdf() , mormalcdf() , the correct form is normpdf() , normcdf()

also you have several endif statements , matlab uses end statements instead.

I can call the following as a function successfully using Matlab 7.9 or GNU Octave 3.2.3 .

```
    function [price,delta,gamma,vega,theta]=BlackScholesPriceTmp(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,v,noutparams)

delta=0; gamma=0; vega=0; theta=0;

b=r;
d1 = (log(S / X) + (b + v ^ 2 / 2) * T) / (v * T^0.5);
d2 = d1 - v * T^0.5;

price=0;

if CallPutFlag == 'c' ,
    price = S * normcdf(d1) - X * exp(-r * T) * normcdf(d2);
end

if noutparams>1,
    delta=exp((b-r)*T)*normcdf(d1);
    theta_tmp1= -( S*exp((b-r)*T)*normpdf(d1)*v )/(2*T^0.5);
    theta_tmp2= -(b-r)*S*exp((b-r)*T)*normcdf(d1);
    theta_tmp3= -r*X*exp(-r*T)*normcdf(d2);
    theta=theta_tmp1+theta_tmp2+theta_tmp3;
else
    price = X * exp(-r * T) * normcdf(-d2) - S * normcdf(-d1);
end

if noutparams>1,
    delta=exp((b-r)*T)*(normcdf(d1)-1);
    theta_tmp1= -( S*exp((b-r)*T)*normpdf(d1)*v )/(2*T^0.5);
    theta_tmp2= (b-r)*S*exp((b-r)*T)*normcdf(-d1);
    theta_tmp3= r*X*exp(-r*T)*normcdf(-d2);
    theta=theta_tmp1+theta_tmp2+theta_tmp3;
end

if noutparams>1,
    gamma=(normpdf(d1)*exp((b-r)*T)) / (S*v*T^0.5);


    vega=S * exp((b-r)*T)*normpdf(d1)*T^0.5;

end
```

Comment: Thanks for doing but I am still getting the same original error. I am currently using Matlab 2010a

Comment: how are you calling the function

Comment: It is very likely that you didn't provide the `r` argument to the function when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to run the function itself. You must call the function externally using `[price,delta,gamma,vega,theta]=BlackScholesPriceTmp(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,v,noutparams)` in the command window (console).  However make sure to initialize each of the inputs with values that you want or you will again receive an error.